# Is it good practice to use @BeanProperty in Scala instead of defining getter/setter functions?

Tags: scala, javabeans

Defining data members in a class that can be publicly accessed/modified

```
var _foo: Int = _
def foo_(foo: Int) = _foo = foo    // setter function
def foo = _foo                     // getter function
```

Is it a good practice to convert this using annotation `@BeanProperty`?

```
import scala.reflect.BeanProperty
@BeanProperty var foo: Int = _
```

and when to use this annotation and when not to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's some redundancy in your first example, since defining a `var` already results in the generation of getters and setters. For example, if we compile this class:

```
class Foo {
  var foo: Int = _
}
```

Then `javap -private Foo` shows the following:

```
public class Foo {
  private int foo;
  public int foo();
  public void foo_$eq(int);
  public Foo();
}
```

Unless you have custom logic that you need to fit into your getters or setters (in which case it's often a good idea to consider more descriptive method names, anyway), you shouldn't need to define them manually.

The `scala.reflect.BeanProperty` annotation (or `scala.beans.BeanProperty` on 2.11) doesn't have any effect on the generation of the `foo()` and `foo_$eq(int)` methods—the compiler will generate these for a `var foo: Int` whether or not you use the annotation. The annotation simply adds `getFoo` and `setFoo` aliases for these methods. If you need these aliases, use the annotation, and if you don't, don't.

To summarize best practices:

1. Don't use `var`.
2. If you have to use `var`, you can (and should) avoid defining your own getters and setters.
3. Use the `BeanProperty` annotation only if you're implementing an interface with `getFoo` and `setFoo`-style method signatures, or if you're expecting your code to be called from Java (where calling methods with names like `foo_$eq` is inconvenient).

Comment: Typo: it should be `scala.beans.BeanProperty`(see api [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.beans.BeanProperty))

Comment: It's not quite clear why you said that using `var` is not a good practice. We just end up with generating getter.setter by scala compiler. Why is it considered bad?

Comment: Thanks, @OlivierCailloux—I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @St.Antario Avoiding mutability is orthogonal to the use of `BeanProperty`—it's a good idea in Scala no matter what.

Answer (score 6):

`@BeanProperty` is meant for Java interoperability, in particular with reflection-based Java frameworks expecting `get` and `set` methods.

Do not use it if you're staying in the Scala world. Use Scala getters (`def foo`) and setters (`def foo_=`) instead.