# Scala - why private member then

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalatest

I am start working on existing Scala and Akka project. I say Scala classes, some fields making them as private and providing getter and setter methods in different way. why like that you can make it as public also right.

I say in my project

Why this way:

```
class Person() {  
 // Private age variable, renamed to _age 
 private var _age = 0 
 var name = "" 

 // Getter 
 def age = _age 

 // Setter 
 def age_= (value:Int):Unit = _age = value 
}
```

So you can get same feeling like public:

```
person.age = 99
```

Why not this simple way?

```
class Person() {  
 var name = "" 
 var age = 0 
} 

// Instantiate a person object 
person = new Person() 

// Print the object's age and name properties 
println(person.age)  
println(person.name) 


// Set the properties to different values 
person.age = 34  
person.name = "Dustin Martin"
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters

Comment: that's called data encapsulation and is one of the main OO programming principles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case there is no reason. If it's from a real project, this was probably copied from an example by someone who didn't understand its point. You only want to use explicit getter/setter methods in Scala when they do something *other* than just mutating a private variable.

(And as Dima's answer correctly says, you should try not to have a `var` in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are bad. Avoid mutable members in classes unless you have a specific reason to use them in a given case.

```
 case class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
   def rename(newName: String) = copy(newName)
   def grow(numYears: Int) = copy(age = this.age + numYears)
 }

 val teen = Person("John", 15) 
 val adult = teen.grow(5)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing and mutating data members of the class directly is the bad idea. Thats why its a good practice to to declare the mutable data member as `private` and provide public getter and setter to access and mutate it (data member).

1) Its a good practice because access to the mutable state should be controlled

2) You can add some validation in the getter and setter like this

for getter

```
def age = if (_age >= 18) _age else throw new Exception("minor")
```

for setter

```
def age_=(age: Int) = if (age < 18) throw new Exception("minor") else _age = age
```

Comment: No, this isn't at all a good practice in Scala. The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters isn't relevant because `var` is already a getter/setter method pair (and a private field), not a public field. When you want e.g. validation, or to only provide a getter for a mutable member, then use explicit getters/setters, not before.

Comment: "It's good practice" isn't really a reason without some sort of justification.

Answer (score 0):

Well it mainly talks about encapsulation. According to Object world, ***You should achieve a state only through an action***. For example I can't reach 100kmph with my car without pushing the accelerator .  So the car speed 100kmph(state) is achieved **only** by acceleration (action).

scala style of getters and setters may give you little confusion but thats all syntactical confusion(during initial days) but  ***Scala does*** ***no compromise on encapsulation***. you can still use java style of getters and setters like below

```
class Car (@BeanProperty val model:String, @BeanProperty val  make:String) {

}
```

Java Bean style of getters and setters would be generated dynamically.But @BeanProperty is meant for Java interoperability.[For more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038977/is-it-good-practice-to-use-beanproperty-in-scala-instead-of-defining-getter-set)